# android app with multiple media players in same activity - how to use efficiently

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am creating an android activity that will have many mediaplayers inside. The activity will have many mediaplayer objects and if i could describe it its like a
    4 X 1 grid of media players.  I created the 4X1 grid by using TextureView class's in android.

so the xml layout for the activity looks like this more or less:

```
<TextureView
android:id="@+id/surface_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <TextureView
    android:id="@+id/surface_two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/surface_three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

            <TextureView
            android:id="@+id/surface_four"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
</LinearLayout>
```

So each textureView will be the surface where the MediaPlayers will play there video.
programatically i've set up SurfaceTextureListener's so that i know when the surface is available like this for each one:

```
TextureView tv1 = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.surface_one);
tv1.setSurfaceTextureListener(new SurfaceListener_1());
```

and likewise for the rest. here is how i would do the second texture view setup:

```
TextureView tv2 = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.surface_two);
 tv2.setSurfaceTextureListener(new SurfaceListener_2());
```

Then in code i am creating 4 MediaPlayer Objects and setting there surface like this for mediaplayer #1:

```
private class SurfaceListener_1 implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Surface sfc = new Surface(surface);
            try {
                m_mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
                m_mp1.setSurface(sfc); //critical , here i am adding the surface so the media player can play on it
                m_mp1.setDataSource(m_context, m_videoUri_one);
                m_mp1.prepareAsync();
                m_mp1.setLooping(true);
                m_mp1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        video1Prepared = true;
                    }
                });
                m_mp1.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener(){
                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
              //release the surface as its now set in the media player
                if(sfc!=null)
                    sfc.release();
            }
        }
        //...... the rest of the call backs not important...
```

and for the other media players i repeat the same thing so that they all have surfaces to play on. here is how i would do mediaplayer # 2:

```
private class SurfaceListener_2 implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Surface sfc = new Surface(surface);
            try {
                m_mp2 = new MediaPlayer();
                m_mp2.setSurface(sfc); //critical , here i am adding the surface so the media player can play on it
                m_mp2.setDataSource(m_context, m_videoUri_two);
                m_mp2.prepareAsync();
                m_mp2.setLooping(true);
                m_mp2.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        video2Prepared = true;
                    }
                });
                m_mp2.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener(){
                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
              //release the surface as its now set in the media player
                if(sfc!=null)
                    sfc.release();
            }
        }
        //...... the rest of the call backs not important...
```

so in the end what i have created is 4 surfaces where i can play a video.  All 4 media players play different video files.
Once all the media players are prepared, i call their start() method on all of them and they play at the same time.

The issue i am facing is that this can be cpu intensive. On some devices i can get a ANR or the app just gets slow to respond.
The media file i am playing is a MP4 and the size of the media files are all about 9 MB.

Is there anything you can recommend so that i can be more cpu efficient in this already heavy task ? For example, can i get the GPU to help ?
Or if i change media type will that make it more efficient ? the video's do not have sound there only visual if that helps.

Comment: the best way I think right now is dont play all the video at the same time. you can loop them like player1 then when it finish playing start playing in player2 and so on.

Comment: No. I need them simultaneously.  It's like video conference app. With 4 people

Comment: you should make it clear that its for video conference. as what you stated in your post to play a video...